How to rename duplicate Columns in Pandas groupby result
I have a dataframe  as such:
  DF = pd.DataFrame(
   {
       'Application Date': ['2023-06-03', '2023-05-15', '2022-02-10', '2021-12-30', '2022-09-01'],
       'Application ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
   }
)
DF['Application Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Application Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
DF.dtypes

I wish to find the number of applications by year and month for which I used the following piece of code
      DF.groupby(
         [DF['Application Date'].dt.year, DF['Application Date'].dt.month]
     ).size()

These result has two columns "Application Date"

How can I rename the first column as "Application Year", second as "Application Month" and last as "No of Applicants"

You can use rename for the grouper columns.
Then if you want to keep them as index and have one column named 'No of Applicants', use agg with a keyword argument using a dict with the new column name as key and a tuple of '(column, aggfunc)' as value:
DF = DF.groupby(
    [
        DF["Application Date"].dt.year.rename("Application Year"),
        DF["Application Date"].dt.month.rename("Application Month"),
    ]
).agg(**{"No of Applicants": ("Application ID", "size")})

                                    No of Applicants
Application Year Application Month                  
2021             12                                1
2022             2                                 1
                 9                                 1
2023             5                                 1
                 6                                 1

Or you can reset_index specifying a name and have all three as columns:
DF = (
    DF.groupby(
        [
            DF["Application Date"].dt.year.rename("Application Year"),
            DF["Application Date"].dt.month.rename("Application Month"),
        ]
    )
    .size()
    .reset_index(name="No of Applicants")
)

   Application Year  Application Month  No of Applicants
0              2021                 12                 1
1              2022                  2                 1
2              2022                  9                 1
3              2023                  5                 1
4              2023                  6                 1


You last piece of code returns a Series, not a dataframe. When you use multiple grouping variables, groupby will use them to create a multiindex. The 2 "columns" with repeating name are actually 2 levels of that multiindex. In my code, I define grouped as:
grouped = DF.groupby(
    [DF['Application Date'].dt.year, DF['Application Date'].dt.month]
).size()

You can either make your changes on your series and then transform it into a dataframe:
(grouped.rename_axis(['Application Year', 'Application Month'])
        .rename('No of Applicants')
        .to_frame()
        .reset_index())

Or reset index first to get a dataframe and then rename the columns:
(grouped.reset_index(allow_duplicates=True)
        .set_axis(['Application Year', 'Application Month', 'No of Applicants'], axis=1))

Both giving the same output
>>> grouped
    Application Year  Application Month  No of Applicants
0               2021                12                1
1               2022                 2                1
2               2022                 9                1
3               2023                 5                1
4               2023                 6                1

